# requests MultiPartForm data with custom authentication

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, authorization

I am using the MultiPartEncoder in the `requests-toolbelt` library on Python 3.9 and 3.10.

`from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder`

I have a custom authentication handler that drops the payload upon checking to see if the request requires a token

When I go to recreate the payload and POST it again, the payload is missing.  What do I need to set to ensure the `data` is moved along with the Authorization header?

```py
token_str = "ABCD123" # fake token for clarity (this works)

r.content
r.raw.release_conn()


if r.request.method == "GET":
    r.request.prepare_url(url=r.url, params={"token": token_str})

elif r.request.method == "POST":
    data = r.request.body
    r.request.prepare_body(data, None, None)
else:
    r.request.headers[
        "Authorization"
    ] = f"Bearer {token_str}"

r.request.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {token_str}"
_r = r.connection.send(r.request, **kwargs)  # this where the request doesn't pass the form data
_r.headers["referer"] = self.referer
_r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {token_str}"
_r.history.append(r)
return _r
```

When I inspect the r (requests.Response object) and the r.request object they contain the payload, so I am a bit baffled why this isn't work.